# Attribute values do not reflect changes made at runtime

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I have a problem and can't wrap my mind around it:
I made a mathode which should set propertie values of an specific attribute "MappingAttribute" and return the new object.

The problem:
The attribute values are always set to the default value "false".
Where am I wrong?

```
    static public T MapToClass<T>(SqlDataReader reader) where T : class
    {
        T returnedObject = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        PropertyInfo[] modelProperties = returnedObject.GetType().GetProperties();
        for (int i = 0; i < modelProperties.Length; i++)
        {
            MappingAttribute[] attributes = modelProperties[i].GetCustomAttributes<MappingAttribute>(true).ToArray();


            if (attributes.Length > 0) {
                attributes[0].AutoIncrement = true;
                attributes[0].Primekey = true;
            }
        }
        return returnedObject;
    }
```

Comment: note: these aren't "custom properties" in any way - they're "attributes"; changing tags/title

Answer (score 2):

Attributes are not *stored* anywhere except in the assembly metadata. They are only materialized into attribute *instances* when asked to do so by reflection - in your case via `GetCustomAttributes<MappingAttribute>`. But: you then discard these. The next time `GetCustomAttributes<MappingAttribute>` is called, **fresh new instances** will be handed out, with the values from the assembly metadata.

Basically: updating properties of attribute instances does *not* mean that other code will see those changes when *that code* asks about attribute metadata.

To illustrate this:

```
using System;
class FooAttribute : Attribute { public string Value { get; set; } }

[Foo(Value = "abc")]
class Bar
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var attrib = (FooAttribute)typeof(Bar)
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FooAttribute), false)[0];
        Console.WriteLine(attrib.Value); // "abc"
        attrib.Value = "def";
        Console.WriteLine(attrib.Value); // "def"

        // now re-fetch
        attrib = (FooAttribute)typeof(Bar)
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FooAttribute), false)[0];
        Console.WriteLine(attrib.Value); // "abc"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Now I understand it!